# Get HTTP header fields only on iPhone

Tags: iphone, http, url, header

I want to get only the headers of an URL request. I have been using stringWithContentsOfURL() for all downloading so far, but now I am only interested in the headers and downloading the entire file is not feasible as it is too large.

I have found solutions which show how to read the headers after the response has been receieved, but how do I specify in the request that I only wish to download headers. Skip the body!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've used. The code below is synchronous but you can make it asynchronous using a delegate.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = ... //init your request...
    NSURLResponse *response=nil;
    NSError *error=nil;

    [newRequest setValue:@"HEAD" forKey:@"HTTPMethod"];
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:newRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    [newRequest release];
    //Get MIME type from the response
    NSString* MIMEType = [response MIMEType];
```

Edited to add replace NSURLRequest with NSMutableRequest.

Comment: You have to use NSMutableURLRequest instead of NSURLRequest and then call setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD". 

I did not confirm whether this works. It should..

Comment: Not to nitpick the nitpicker. But, replacing "..." with  "[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:..." in the above answer works. So, technically, the answer is not wrong. Bad faith always wins ;) As for Synchronous/asynchronous debate, it is off topic. Dan is right though.

Comment: Hm, you're right... I'll take back my downvote, however I need the answer to be edited to do that it seems. =)

Answer (score 11):

Asynchronously send a HEAD request to the URL in question and then just access the `allHeaderFields` property on `HTTPURLResponse` / `NSHTTPURLResponse`.

#### Swift 4

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com/")!)
request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        let headers = response.allHeaderFields as? [String: String] else {
        return
    }
}
task.resume()
```

#### Objective-C

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
                       }];
```

Comment: Preferred over @FKDev's answer, since this one suggest using the asynchronous API - and does use `NSMutableURLRequest` correctly. ;)

Answer (score 2):

only implement didReceiveResponse delegate method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode];
}
```