# How do I find out type of file from URL?

Tags: ios, url, file-type

If a URL ends with just a string of characters, and no extension. i.e.:

```
http://example/1234567890
```

...and I know contains either a PNG, JPG or GIF. How do I find out which one it is without downloading the whole file. I'm asking because I need to do something completely different with it if it's a GIF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a header request and look for the mime type as was posted here:

[Get HTTP header fields only on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565734/887210)

[Complete List of MIME Types](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)